# Sorting Data using Firebase in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a website using ReactJS and Firebase, and now, I'm stuck on sorting the data, I've already tried and taken a look on this, but I'm stuck, here's my last (trying) code

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.orderByChild('judul').nameonSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  };
```

and this

```
onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const jadwal = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { url, judul, keterangan, nowa, selectedDate } = doc.data();
      jadwal.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc,
        url,
        judul,
        keterangan,
        nowa,
        selectedDate,
      });
    });
    this.setState(
      {
        jadwal,
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.jadwal);
      }
    );
  };
```

and this is what I got

[got an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlkLm.png)

I think this is the closest code that I try to make it functional (in my opinion), but it doesn't, can you guys help me? I really appreciate if you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what, now i know how to sorting the firebase.database using this code:

```
this.ref2 = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("jadwal")
      .where("selectedDate", ">", moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
      .orderBy("selectedDate")
      .limit(3);
```

it will ordering by "selectedDate" and liming the data by 3